# Generate Virtual Pageview via .js OnClick event in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, javascript

I have some expanding sections (via .js) and I want to see when the user clicks those.

So, in the OnClick event I want to attach some .js to fire off a virtual pageview. (I know how to fire an Event but I want a Pageview so I can use it in Goals)

And here is the .js I'm using .

I suspect I can just change the 'event' parameter to something else (pageview ??)

```
    <script>

/**
* Function that tracks a click on an outbound link in Analytics.
*/
var trackOutboundLink = function(url) {
   ga('send', 'event', 'outbound', 'click', url, {
     'transport': 'beacon',
     'hitCallback': function(){document.location = url;}
   });
}
</script>
```

Comment: I added an answer bellow, did you try it?

Answer (score 1):

According to [Google Analytics Docs](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/pages), "pageview hits can be sent using the `send` command and specifying a hitType of `pageview`"

Example in your case :

```
<script>

/**
 * Function that tracks a click on an outbound link in Analytics.
 */
var trackOutboundLink = function(url) {
   ga('send', 'pageview', url, {
     'transport': 'beacon',
     'hitCallback': function(){document.location = url;}
   });
}
</script>
```

I would test it, since I am not sure that `hitCallback`is supported in this case. If not, Google suggest another (similar) format in its doc.